# Craft Commerce: ordering products like a structure

Tags: sorting, order, plugin-craftcommerce3

Is it possible to change the order of products in Craft Commerce (3) by drag & drop? Just like it is done with the entries of a structure?

If not, how am I supposed to change the order of products?
Of course I can create a number field and type in a number and then sort after this number. But that's super inconvinient.
Another way would be to create single-pages for each product category and then have an entries-field. Than, at least, I can use drag and drop. But still, this would just be a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

Yeh there's few workarounds.

Your entries field is close to what Nathanial from P&T [mentioned](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/229) on the issue tracker:

> If you create a global set and add a custom product field. Then select all the products. This gives you the ability to drag and drop the order of the products. You can use this in conjunction with the on save event and catch the save of new products and programmatically add them to the field mentioned above.

If you filter by category, you won't have to create a field for every category however it's definitely still a workaround.

[image]

One other option would be to sort based on some other criteria that's always around, such as date created or modified.

If you want something to float to top or bottom, just remove the post date (so Craft will make the product the current date and time) or resave the product (to change the modification date). Depending on how you sort that could be a quick way to move products to the top for example.

Make sure you [chime in](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/229) on that issue on the tracker to give it more attention.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link to the issue! A workaround is not what I'm looking for. I think it's strange that this functionality is missing for products but exists for other entries ...

Comment: @obs Yeh even though Commerce is first party, there are a number of things that I wish were built into commerce that entries have which products don't inherit (including revisions).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official knowledge base article on how to do it...

https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/manually-sorting-commerce-products

Albeit that's fine if you've only got a handful of products, as soon as you have hundreds it becomes unmanageable. Would be good if there was a search on this solution and the ability to push a selected product to the top (for large lists).